# How to add additional topic permissions in RBMQ with definitions.json

Tags: rabbitmq

Does anybody know how to give a user additional topic permissions (e.g. amq.topic) through the definitions.json config file? (I know it's possible through the management console, but I don't want to set it up manually.)

I already tried following which is not giving any additional topic permissions:

```
{
  "user": "guest",
  "vhost": "/",
  "configure": ".*",
  "write": ".*",
  "read": ".*"
},
{
  "user": "guest",
  "vhost": "/",
  "configure": "amq.topic",
  "write": ".*",
  "read": ".*"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a topic_permissions section, with the config you want:

```
"topic_permissions": [
    {
        "user": "guest",
        "vhost": "/",
        "exchange": "amq.topic",
        "write": "[^.]+\\.sample\\.[^.]+",
        "read": ""
    }
]
```

To figure out those things, I usually create them manually in the admin interface, then export the definition to see how it is "translated".

Comment: To show the definitions with the admin interface was actually a very good hint. I use now rabbitmqctl list_topic_permissions --formatter json

Answer (score 0):

See `topic_permissions` section from (fill user/pass):

```
curl --silent --user yourusername:yourpass --header "Content-type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/definitions | jq . | tee config.json
```

Or example without exchange:

```
"topic_permissions": [
  {
    "user": "yourusername",
    "vhost": "/",
    "exchange": "",
    "write": ".*",
    "read": ".*"
  }
]
```